# App Transport Security Settings not working on port 8000

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-transport-security

I have allowed Arbitrary Loads in my info.plist
however it's sill blocking my connection.

I think my problem is with the port number of my Stream URL which is 8000

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sub.domain.ext:8000/\(_qualities[currentQuality])"];

player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

Comment: Are you sure about the url `http://sub.domain.ext:8000`? try using https

Comment: yes the url is correct ... it's http ... in browser it gives me a live stream ... if I use https: `Protocol not available`

Comment: Are you sure about the last part of the string (i.e. `\(_qualities[currentQuality])`)?  That looks like Swift syntax to me, which of course won't work the way you expect in Objective-C code.

Comment: http://sub.domain.ext:8000/64 yes the output was incorrect but now it's ok ... still NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)

Comment: Can you show your Info.plist?  If you have NSAllowArbitraryLoads this should work.  I think maybe something is wrong with your Info.plist.

Comment: Also, when you get to the point of it working, you may consider using the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia` key instead to narrow what can load without ATS.  It is iOS 10 only, but I believe it will allow you to submit to the app store without a justification to Apple.